# How to handle special symbols in twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

What I need

- I need to show special symbols in view page.

  ```
         say name: Sara Fernström oksss.
  ```

  php code

  ```
        {% set  name=value.metadata.name %}

    <h3>

       {%if name|length < 40 %}

  {% set strategy = 'html' %}

   {% autoescape 'html' %}
   {{name|escape(strategy)|raw}}
  {% endautoescape %}
  ```

refrence

- http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/escape.html

output :

```
    Sara Fernstru00f6m
```

but o/p should be:

```
    Sara Fernström oksss
```

Comment: Have you ever tried to simply output `{{ name }}`? Without all this strategy an escaping thingy? Twig should handle strings properly from the beginning.

Comment: If you retrieve the value from a database check the correct encoding on that.

Comment: Hi @user4041461 have you find a solutions?

Comment: no problem has not solved , when i change spansih char in db my api wn"t run only print_r works>>@@@

Comment: Hi, i don't understand: if you change the charset, you can print correctly via twig? What problem do you have in the API? PS: if you don't tag me in the comment i will not notify of your comment

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is not with Twig, your issue is with your page and string encoding.

Make sure the string is UTF-8 before it is passed to Twig.
Make sure the document is UTF-8.

Then use

```
{{ data }}
```

to output your string.

I work with åöä all the time(swedish) and literally never had to use anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to decode the string in the proper charset:

```
{{ data|convert_encoding('UTF-8', 'YourCharset') }}
```

data will be your string, the first value is the output-charset the second the input-charset, you can also see the twig doc for this: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/convert_encoding.html

If the this doesn't work maybe try to [decode](http://%C2%B4http://php.net/manual/de/function.utf8-decode.php) the variable inside your php `code`:
For your code it would be something like this I think:

```
value.metadata.setName(utf8_decode(value.metadata.getName());
```

Comment: string  Sara Fernstru00f6m still visible

Comment: i need   Sara Fernström oksss should be output

Comment: What's wrong with `UTF-8` that you suggest OP to convert?

Comment: I think in this case it must be like this `{{ data|convert_encoding('YourCharset', 'UTF-8') }}` to get it to work do you agree?

Answer (score 0):

Check how you store the data in your database with the **charset** and **collate** params as example:

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyEntityRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="my_entity",
 *      options={"collate"="utf8mb4_unicode_ci", "charset"="utf8mb4"})})
 */
class MyEntity
{
  ....
```

Hope this help

Comment: Hi @user4041461 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. please consider to upvote my answer if you find it useful